# Error when attempting to upload file to Azure VM via SFTP

Tags: azure, sftp

I receive the following error when attempting to upload certain files to my VM via SFTP:

Network error: Software caused connection abort

I had thought it was related to file type (dll), as it had worked for text, php, and html files, but after further testing it had also failed with zip and png files.  I have tried both WinSCP and Filezilla, both generate the same error.  I am fairly certain that it is being caused by some security or permission setting within the Azure portal but have no idea where to start looking.

Any suggestions?

Comment: enable port 22 on Azure portal, use the Networking tab under your virtual machine settings page.

Comment: Could you please check that,  are you able to telnet SFTP port ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry unable to comment, but this is not really an answer.

Issue is not with 'Azure' blocking anything **might be with your FTP configuration on the VM**.  To confirm just deploy a VM in Azure and FTP works just fine.

[image]

Hope this helps.